# DataSet iteration inconstant results

Tags: apache-flink

DataSet iteration returning different results for different execution. 
Sometimes, size of the result is not matching the printed number of output values.

I cannot share the complete code here, but I can share it directly if anyone wants to have a look.

**Edit 1:**
**biscuitfresh**'s answer fixed the mismatching size and iterated values issue. But I am **still facing the actual issue of getting different results for different runs with the same input**.

```
 DataSet<Tuple5<Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer,Boolean>> finalVals = iterativeDataSet.closeWith(finalAlive);

    try {

        int size = finalVals.collect().size();
        finalVals.collect().forEach(val-> System.out.printf("row %d, col %d neighbors %d alive? %b\n",val.f1,val.f2,val.f3,val.f4));
        return size;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The above code sometimes printing lesser values than returned size and sometime more values than returned size. Any clue on why it happens?

**Edit 2:**
Identified the bug in my code for different results. It is due flag reset in one of the mapper. Accepted **biscuitfresh**'s as it points out issue in the posted code snippet.

Answer (score 1):

Try calling `finalVals.collect()` only once to make sure you are definitely working on the same collection (that hasn't changed). Then you should get a matching amount of results.

Comment: Thanks, that solved the issue of mismatching size and iterated values but I am sill facing different results for different runs issue.